# Contiuning Crontab Script on Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action\

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I get the Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action\ error on occassion when a user changes their password, and I want to continue the crontab script, not causing it to end in a fatal error so I can handle the other users....

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So catch the exception! It's only a fatal error if your script doesn't catch it.

If you're not familiar with exceptions in PHP, they're documented at: http://php.net/language.exceptions